# What is the correct notation for showing something is a union of many sets?

Tags: notation

If I wanted to show this would it look something like

```
Whatchamacallets = (Things + Stuff + Pandas)
```

Comment: $\bigcup_{x\in I} A_x$ would be the notation for the union of a bunch of sets $A_x$.  In your example you could also do $W=T\cup S\cup P$.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to toss this in as an answer I will mark it for you. Even though it is a math softball it was something I needed.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the indexed sum notation that looks like:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n x^2 + 1$$

There's a similar union notation.

$$\bigcup_{i=0}^n S_i$$

Comment: I guess $x$ is a typo and should be $i$, or $x_i$